# Как использовать задержку сигнала с помощью sigwait()

Tags: c++, linux, clion, signal

по заданию мне нужно написать программу родителя, который открывает канал pipe и порождает два процесса потомка и после этого родитель заполняет канал из входного файла и после этого отправляет сигнал SIGQUIT потомкам, которые по очереди читают по символу из канала и отправляют друг другу сигналы после прочтения очередного символа SIGUSR1 и SIGUSR2 чтобы другой потомок смог начать читать, но появилась проблема: на цикле чтения у родителя происходит ступор, причем если дебажу по шагам то все нормально и он выходит из цикла или если убираю строчки вызова exec, то выход из цикла происходит. Не понимаю в чем может быть проблема. В потомках использую sigwait для ожидания. Коды родителя и потомков представлю ниже. Подскажите пожалуйста что не так? Код родителя:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <wait.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    sigset_t new_mask;
    sigemptyset(&new_mask);
    sigaddset(&new_mask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&new_mask, SIGUSR2);
    sigaddset(&new_mask, SIGQUIT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &new_mask, NULL);
    int fildes[2];
    pipe(fildes);
    pid_t pid1;
    pid_t pid2;
    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) {
        //execl("1","1", "output1.txt", &fildes[0], &fildes[1],NULL);
        close(fildes[0]);
        _exit(0);
    }
    else {
        pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 == 0) {
            execl("2","2", "output2.txt", &fildes[0], &fildes[1], NULL);
            close(fildes[0]);
            _exit(0);
        }
        else {
            close(fildes[0]);
            cout<<"Parent"<<endl;
            ifstream file("input.txt");
            if (file.is_open()) {
                string str;
                bool t = true;
                t = (bool)getline(file, str);
                while(t){
                    write(fildes[1], &str[0], strlen(str.c_str()));
                    cout<<"PARENT пишет:" << str << endl;
                    cout<< "sdsdsds";
                    t = (bool)getline(file, str);
                }
                cout << "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
                killpg(0, SIGQUIT);
                file.close();
            }
            int st1, st2;
            waitpid(pid1, &st1, 0);
            waitpid(pid2, &st2, 0);
            close(fildes[1]);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Код первого потомка:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <cerrno>  

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int fildes[2];
    fildes[0]=*argv[2];
    fildes[1]=*argv[3];
    close(fildes[1]);
    sigset_t mask_sig;
    sigemptyset(&mask_sig);
    sigaddset(&mask_sig, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&mask_sig, SIGQUIT);
    ofstream file;
    int last_sig;
    char ch;
    file.open(argv[1], ios::app);
    //file << read(fildes[0], &ch, 1)  << endl;
    sigwait(&mask_sig, &last_sig);
    file << read(fildes[0], &ch, 1)  << endl;
    file << errno << endl;
    file << "a" << endl;
    while(read(fildes[0], &ch, 1) > 0){
        //file << "a" << endl;
        file << ch;
        killpg(0, SIGUSR2);
        sigwait(&mask_sig, &last_sig);
    }
    killpg(0, SIGUSR2);
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Код второго потомка:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <wait.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int fildes[2];
    fildes[0]=*argv[2];
    fildes[1]=*argv[3];
    close(fildes[1]);
    sigset_t mask;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGQUIT);
    sigset_t mask_sig;
    sigemptyset(&mask_sig);
    sigaddset(&mask_sig, SIGUSR2);
    ofstream file;
    int last_sig;
    char ch;
    file.open(argv[1], ios::app);
    //sigwait(&mask, &last_sig);
    sigwait(&mask_sig, &last_sig);
    while(read(fildes[0], &ch, 1) > 0){
        file << ch;
        killpg(0, SIGUSR1);
        sigwait(&mask_sig, &last_sig);
    }
    killpg(0, SIGUSR1);
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не стал читать весь код до конца, т.к. того, что я увидел уже хватило :-)

1. Отлаживать **мультипроцессную** программу отладчиком, это то же самое, что изучать "штопор" на самолёте, стоящем на земле. Отстутствует самое главное - движение.
2. После функции *fork()*, первое проверяемое условие *if (pid < 0)* а вовсе не *if (pid==0)*
3. И в главном процессе и в дочернем Вы выполняете вызов *close(fildes[0]);*. Т.е. и там и тут Вы закрываете канал ввода. В родительском - понятно. А в дочернем - зачем? Как Вы собираетесь оттуда читать, если вы его закрыли?!
4. В вызове функции *execl()* **все** параметры имеют тип *char **. Никаких *&fildes[0]* имеющих тип *int ** там быть не может.

Дальше смотреть не стал, т.к. пока эти ошибки не исправлены, анализировать поведение программы смысла нет.

И последнее - "1" и "2" - это у Вас что - действительные названия исполнимых модулей? Тогда система **не** найдёт ваши ELF-ы. Первые два параметра в этих вызовах должны выглядеть как-то так:

```
execl("./1","1",...
execl("./2","2",...
```